# Exceeding the "rules" quota in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm constantly exceeding my quota in firebase. I don't understand why the "rules" quota is always exceeded, how does this happen? for what reason could this be? I don't use exist(), get() anywhere. i have a small number of reads. I provide screenshots below

[image: rules]

[image: another metricts]

this is my rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore database appears to have  very lenient security rules, allowing full read and write access to all documents.

While this may be suitable for initial development and testing, it is not  recommended  for  production environments due to the potential security and cost implications.

The exceeded Firebase quota may be related to the number of reads and writes, as the rule allows full access to all documents.

Even if your application does not explicitly use the `exist()` or `get()` functions, any read operations involving lists of documents or sub-collections can affect quota usage.

To mitigate this, consider adjusting your security rules to restrict access to only the documents and collections that your application requires.

This reduces unnecessary reads and writes and gives you better control over your Firebase usage.

For example, you can update  rules to restrict access to specific paths.

```
plaintext service cloud.firestore { match /databases/{database}/documents { match /users/{userId} { Allow read and write: if request.auth.uid == userId; } } }
```

This example provides a more secure and efficient structure because only authenticated users can read and write documents in the users collection.

Test your security rules thoroughly to ensure they meet the needs of your application before deploying them in a production environment.

Comment: The OP already knows they have very permissive rules, and it's not a quota problem for that to be the case. Making the rules less permissive isn't an option when the rules are already working as intended.

Comment: I don't understand where 100k comes from if everything else is very little. aren't "rules" related to reading etc?